# RxSwift - Does disposing of a subscription cause the underlying sequence to emit onComplete?

Tags: swift, reactive

I'm reading this book about RxSwift "Reactive Programming with Swift 4" by Packt (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/reactive-programming-with/9781787120211/). In one section, the book says:

> "Disposing of a subscription will cause the underlying Observable
>   sequence to emit a completed event and terminate"

However I found out that the phrase is not correct. Here's an example:

```
        let publisher = PublishSubject<Int>() //Create an <Int> sequence
        let subscription1 = publisher.asObservable() //Create 1st subscription
            .debug("Subscription 1")
            .subscribe { (event) in
            print(event)
        }
        let subscription2 = publisher.asObservable() //Create 2nd subscription
            .debug("Subscription 2")
            .subscribe { (event) in
                print(event)
        }
        publisher.onNext(1) //Emit first event
        subscription1.dispose() //Dispose the 1st subscription. According to the phrase above, publisher should emit an onComplete event
        publisher.onNext(2) //Emit second event
```

As my comment in the code says, at *subscription1.dispose()*, *publisher* should've emit an onComplete event, but in fact it can still emit new events as normal, thus the output:

```
2018-11-01 19:43:59.796: Subscription 1 -> subscribed
2018-11-01 19:43:59.798: Subscription 2 -> subscribed
2018-11-01 19:43:59.798: Subscription 1 -> Event next(1)
next(1)
2018-11-01 19:43:59.798: Subscription 2 -> Event next(1)
next(1)
2018-11-01 19:43:59.799: Subscription 1 -> isDisposed
2018-11-01 19:43:59.799: Subscription 2 -> Event next(2)
next(2)
```

Can anyone confirm that my understanding in correct? Or did I miss anything behind the scene of RxSwift?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding about unsubscribing is correct: disposing of a subscription does not cause a onComplete to run. However when an onComplete or an onError is reached it will automatically unsubscribe (http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html the Subscribing and Unsubscribing section is really useful)

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this question via Google, so will answer more thoroughly for anyone who might be having similar questions.

The whole misunderstanding here is caused by there being 2 different types of observables:

1. Cold observables.
2. Hot observables.

Cold observables are closely related to their subscriptions. They do not initiate any action until they are subscribed to and will terminate as soon as you dispose all of their subscriptions. These are the ones from the book quotation.

Hot observables start whatever they are designed to do as soon as they are created and regardless of their current subscribers. They will always run until their internal action completes, no matter if they have currently 5 subscribers or none. These are the ones from your example.

Always be mindful which type of observable you are currently using. For example cold observable's action may be started separately for each subscriber, so if for example you're dealing with http requests, be careful not to initiate the same request many times by subscribing more than once. On the other hand, the main pitfall with hot observables is exactly in your question - it will not terminate until it's done with it's action.

Hope that can clear up some confusion.